# How to pop Navigation in swrevealviewcontroller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I have application like facebook and I want to know how to Pop Frontview controller SWRevealViewController?

Following code is use to push frontviewcontroller from rearview controller.suppose front view controller have back button now i want to pop dashboard.How can I do that.

**Code**

```
AwardsViewController *awardsVC = [[AwardsViewController alloc]init];

SWRevealViewController *revealController = self.revealViewController;

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = (id)revealController.frontViewController;

NSString *suffix = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? @"AwardsViewController_iPad" : @"AwardsViewController";

 awardsVC=[[AwardsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:suffix bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:awardsVC];

[revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

**Images to understand**

1) [Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTrKI.jpg)
2) [SWRevealViewController (Rear)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3siqd.png)
3) [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5AjY.jpg)

**Description**

when I am Login then Display Dashboard Now I click on Rear View controller.In rear view controller click on any facebook contact then navigate to his profile. now I want to pop like facebook in my app using SWRevealViewController.

**Navigation like**

Dashboard > Click On Rear > Click on Any Contact > push forntview controler > now i want to pop on dashboard

Thanks

Any help appriciate.

Comment: `SWRevealViewController's` menu have in build push segue's to transit, you can create a button for that or try overriding rear button (i haven't tried).

Comment: Button is aleready created.but problem with pop. I can push on back button but that's not proper wway

Comment: confusion here.. you need to push back your app to dashboard when you transit with `SWRevealViewController's` menu?, share screenshot please.

Comment: In sort when I press back button pop to dashboard(like facebook).